# Adding content using MVVM pattern with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui, xcode12

I've a problem.
So, I've a View to add a new content on my app, I've a Model and a ViewModel.

1. is it possible to use Model for two-way binding?(on the form)
2. How to collect all the form data and append it to all the available Goals? knowing that some of the Model property will be empty

I don't know how to do that.
Here my view

```
import SwiftUI

#if canImport(UIKit)
extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
#endif

struct NewGoalView: View {
    @State private var categories = ["Health and hospital bills", "Food", "Clothing/Fashion", "Electronics/Smart devices", "Transportation", "Investment", "Rent", "Fees", "Payoff debts", "Start business", "Emergency", "Others"]
    @State private var category:Int = 0
    @State private var projectName:String = ""
    @State private var amount:String = ""
    @State private var duration:Date = Date()
    @State private var interest:Bool = true
// Alert or modal presentation variables
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State var showAlert: Bool = false
    
    private func endEditing() {
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form{
            Section{
                Text("Pick a category for your goal").foregroundColor(.secondary)
                Picker("Category", selection: $category){
                    ForEach(0..<categories.count, id: \.self){
                        Text(categories[$0]).tag($0)
                    }
                }
            }
            Section{
                TextField("Your goal name", text: $projectName)
                TextField("The amount you want to raise", text: $amount)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }
            Section{
                Text("When do you want to achieve it?").foregroundColor(.secondary)
                DatePicker("Duration", selection: $duration, in:Date()..., displayedComponents: [.date]).datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
            }
            Section{
                Toggle("Interest on saving", isOn: $interest)
            }
        }.gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ (value) in
            self.endEditing()
        }))
        
        .navigationBarTitle("New piggy bank space", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Cancel",action: {self.isPresented = false}), trailing: Button("Save",action: {
            print("Saved")
            showAlert =  true
        }).alert(isPresented: $showAlert){
            Alert(title: Text("Success"), message: Text("You've successfully set your new goal"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")){
                self.isPresented = false
            })
        })
    }
}

struct NewGoalView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewGoalView(isPresented: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

My Model

```
struct Goal: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID
    var name: String
    var amount: Double  
    var raised: Double
    var priority: String
    var status: String
    var image: String
}
```

My ViewModel

```
class GoalViewModel:ObservableObject {
    @Published var goals: [Goal] = [
        .init(id: UUID(), name: "MacBook Pro", amount: 900000.00, raised: 234000, priority: "high", status: "in process", image: "macbook"),
        .init(id: UUID(), name: "iPad Pro", amount: 780000.00, raised: 380000, priority: "high", status: "in process", image: "ipad"),
        .init(id: UUID(), name: "AirPods Pro", amount: 180000.00, raised: 150000, priority: "high", status: "in process", image: "airpods")
    ]
    
    
    func create(goal: Goal) {
        goals.append(goal)
    }
}
```

Can someone helps me?

Comment: You could use GoalViewModel as ObservedObject in NewGoalView.

Comment: Your first six State properties in the view should be moved to the view model as Published properties and then you add a view model property to the view and access the model properties from the view via the view model.

Comment: In MVVM, your view observes the "view state" (which is produced by the ViewModel, and it will be the published properties of your ObservableObject) and renders it accordingly. The View does not modify the view state - instead is sends "actions" to the ViewModel, which  in turn may alter the view state. In SwiftUI a `@State` variable defines a view _private_ state which is unrelated to the ViewModel's view state. That is, a `@State` is completely orthogonal to the view state and never is a view state or never complements it. Using a` @State` in MVVM could be a smell.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson can you show me an example?
I'm learning Swift and SwiftUI